# Solve the equation $\sqrt3\left|\cos x\right|=1+\cot x$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the equation
$$\sqrt3\left|\cos x\right|=1+\cot x$$

**My work**:

**i)**
Let $\cos x \ge 0$. Then we have got the equation
$$\sqrt3 \cos x =1+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$
$$\sqrt3 \cos x \sin x =\sin x+\cos x$$
$$\frac {\sqrt3}2\sin 2x=\sqrt2 \sin (x+\frac{\pi}4)$$

What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: with $y:=x+\pi/4,\,s:=\sin y$ this is $-\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(2y)=\sqrt{2}\sin y$, i.e. $\sqrt{3}s^2-\sqrt{2}s-\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=0$.

Note if we shift $x$ by $\pi$ we change the sign of $\cos x$ while preserving $\cot x,\,|\cos x|$, so the $\cos x\ge0$ solutions easily give the others.

Comment: And this is only in the case, "If x\geq 0"?

Comment: @amWhy You mean $\cos x\ge0$. I've made an edit to discuss the case $\cos x<0$.

Comment: Yes.  You haven't answered the entire question.  Unless you want to wait for the OP to ask a separate question "I'm stuck when $\cos x \lt 0$?

Comment: @amWhy If the OP uses my first sentence to finish the $\ge0$ case, my second sentence will prevent any need for a $<0$ question, so you've mischaracterised the completeness of my answer.